# One form redirect to multiple html pages

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i would like to know if its possible

One form
Different values
When click submit it will redirect to different pages equal to value input on the form

=======

```
<form name='home' type='get' action='html1.html'>

<input type='text' name='code' value=''>

<input type='image' onclick='return check(this.form)' value='login'

Script:

Function check(form)
{
If(form.user.value == "html1")
{
       Return true;
}
else
{
       Location.href = "error.html";
       Return false;
}
}
```

===============

So again what im trying to do is to creat a form with a single text box where the user will input either html1, html2, html3 and so on.

If the user enter html1 on the form text box and click submit button it will redirect to html1 page if the user enter html2 to the text box and click submit button it will redirect to html2 and so on.

Thanks in advance guys!

If the user enter html1 on the form text box and click submit button it will redirect to html1 page if the user enter html2 to the text box and click submit button it will redirect to html2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do like this, but this will work for you:

**html**

```
<input type='text' id="txturl" name='code' value=''>
<input type='image' onclick='check(this)' value='login'>
```

**Javsacript**

```
function check(form)
 {
   var txtURL=document.getElementById("txturl");
   if(txtURL.value == "html1")
    {
      return true;
    }
   else
    {
      window.location.href = "error.html";
    }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramsingh333/jzacf0kd/5/

Comment: It doesnt seems to be working when i entered the html1 in the text box it redirect to error.html and vise versa

Comment: html1 returns true, it will submit the form when it returns true.

Comment: What about the other page?

Comment: @Scriptkiddo, you can add as much as conditions you want.

Comment: Will this work as well in html file?

Comment: of course, you just need to add jquery reference to the html file.